# Manipular estado

Tags: react, typescript

Estou precisando de ajuda para passar um estado de um componente para o outro, e depois usar ele para fazer uma condição.

Já tenho o retorno do metodo get nesse estado "setFilmes"

```
axios.get<Filmes[]>('http://localhost:3004/filmes')
  .then(function (response) {
    const { data } = response;
    setFilmes(data)
```

Agora preciso passar ele para um componente filho, depois fazer uma condição dentro dele, para verificar se o id atual, é o id que eu preciso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passe o resultado nas *props* do componente filho, e depois acesse esse valor por lá, deste jeito:

Componente pai:

```
export const ComponentePai = () => {
  const [filmes,setFilmes]=useState()

  axios.get<Filmes[]>('http://localhost:3004/filmes')
  .then(function (response) {
    const { data } = response;
    setFilmes(data);
  }

  // apenas retornar se já foi atribuido valor a *filme*
  return ({filmes && <ComponenteFilho filmes={filmes}/>})
}
```

Componente filho:

```
export const ComponenteFilho = ({filmes}) => {
  console.log(filmes); // acessar valor passado no componente pai
  
  return <div>Componente Filho</div>
}
```

Comment: Deu certo. Obrigado!